# Postman: add a given header to all requests in the given collection or collection-level header

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

My question:
Postman: add a given header to all requests in the given collection or collection-level header.

Details (like screenshots):
I have “x-apikey” header & a bunch of requests in the collection without this specific header.
How can I avoid manual work of adding header one by one to each request?
Anyone has an existing solution, please?

How I found the problem:
Imported OpenAPI spec & it does not contain the needed header. Hence, need to add to each request.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be able to do this in your `Pre-request Scripts` at the Collection level.

```
pm.request.headers.add({key: 'x-apikey', value: 'token_value' })
```

Comment: It has to appear in a header of every collection request, hasn't it?